# Download .class file and load it into JVM

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

How can I download .class file and and load it into jvm using class loader , I have write a simple code simulates downloading a .class file the I tried to load it into JVM

```
public class face {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    File f = new File("Task.class");

    int count;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    StringBuilder all = new StringBuilder();
    while ((count = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        // System.out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        all.append(buffer);
        // System.out.flush();
    }
    File b = new File("Task.class");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(b);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
    dos.write(all.toString().getBytes());
    ClassLoader lod = face.class.getClassLoader();
    lod.loadClass(b.getAbsolutePath());

}
}
```

Comment: any errors? why doesn't it work? add this info to improve the question

Answer (score 0):

Use `Class.forName(<package_qualified_class_name>)`

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to applogies for the long list of suggestion here, but you have managed to cram an impressive number of mistakes into a small piece of code.

I suggest don't do any of these things

- don't use DataInputStream or DataOutputStream when it doesn't add anything.  You don't use any method which requires it.
- don't write binary data to a StringBuilder. A StringBuilder is for text.
- don't copy an entire buffer if you only read part of it. i.e. you need to record the length actual read and copy only the amount used.
- don't append a byte[] to a StringBuilder.  It won't do what you expect.
- don't use a String to store binary data.
- don't convert a String to byte[] using the default encoding unless you know you have ASCII data (which you don't)
- don't write to a file you just read. As this doesn't make sense.  You should have tested this works without the file copy and you would have found this didn't work, before you attempted something more complicated.
- you can't write to a file which you still have open in windows. I suggest you close() a file when you are finished with it.
- don't attempt to load a class using the file name.  You load it by package.class name.

I suggest you try a one liner to load a class first and show this works.  The class should appear in your class path, and when you write to the file, you should write it to a directory appropriate for the package.

Instead of doing all this, you could add a `http://yourserver/basepath` to your class path and it will load the classes from a web service. i.e. you might be able to do this without writing any code at all.